# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin{(n\pi/4)} /(\sqrt{n+2}-1)= 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to prove the limit of $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin{(n\pi/4)}}{\sqrt{n+2}-1}= 0$$ I have to use the limit definition to do this, but i get stuck with the $\sin(n\pi/4)$ part. I know how to do the $1/(\sqrt{n+2}-1)$ part, any help?

Comment: Please explicitly include your attempt so we can help you where you are stuck. Also please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical expressions to make them readable.

Comment: Please use latex to write formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hint:$$\frac {-1}{\sqrt{n+2}-1} \leq\frac {\sin (\frac {n\pi}{4})}{\sqrt{n+2}-1}\leq \frac {1}{\sqrt{n+2}-1}$$ apply limit definition then , or $$0\leq |\frac {\sin (\frac {n\pi}{4})}{\sqrt{n+2}-1}| \leq \frac {1}{\sqrt{n+2}-1}$$ so  for the lilit definition $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$ you can rewrite
$$0\leq |\frac {\sin (\frac {n\pi}{4})}{\sqrt{n+2}-1}-0| \leq \frac {1}{\sqrt{n+2}-1}<\epsilon$$

Comment: Thanks, it was so obvious:D